# How to Install Node 8.15 on alpine:3.9?

Tags: dockerfile

I want to install node 8.15 on alpine:3.9

This is my Dockerfile but it is not working.

After docker build I got this error: You need to run "nvm install default" to install it before using it.

Thanks.

```js
FROM alpine:3.9

ENV METEOR_VERSION=1.8.1
ENV METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER true
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.15
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm

RUN mkdir $NVM_DIR

# Install dependencies
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk --no-cache add curl

# Install NVM
RUN curl -o- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh" | bash

# Install NODE
RUN echo "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install $NODE_VERSION && \
    nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION && \
    nvm use default" | bash

# Install METEOR
RUN curl "https://install.meteor.com/?release=${METEOR_VERSION}" | /bin/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you are installing with NVM when we have nodejs in alpine offical repository? each Docker image should represent a version of nodejs. So I will not suggest NVM in this case also will keep the image small.

You can find version  [alpine-pacakge-nodejs v8.x](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=v3.8).

```
FROM alpine:3.9

ENV METEOR_VERSION=1.8.1
ENV METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER true
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.15
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/ nodejs=8.14.0-r0 npm 

RUN node --version
```

output

```
Step 6/6 : RUN node --version
 ---> Running in 9652a49223fa
v8.14.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for a couple of days I was trying to figure out how to install a lower version of node on Alpine without having to downgrade ruby:alpine image.